# How to handle long SQL queries on JPA name query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create an API using spring boot 1.5, hibernate 5.2, mysql

I already tried `@NamedQuery` and `@NamedNativeQuery` on my model but still won't work for long queries (see below).

I tried HQL but some Native SQL syntax (like LIMIT) doesn't work on hql. I put my long hql query on `jpa-named-queries.properties` file so that I can keep my models clean. Below is my formatted HQL query (didn't include all fields on select):

```
SELECT slsum.sl_brcode, loan.loantr_date, slsum.sl_clientid, slsum.sle_code, slsum.slc_code, slsum.slt_code, slsum.ref_no, (CASE WHEN slsum.slc_code = 13 THEN (SELECT arxxref_no FROM Ar ar WHERE ar.arbr_code = slsum.sl_brcode AND ar.arslc_code = slsum.slc_code AND ar.arslt_code = slsum.slt_code AND ar.arref_no = slsum.ref_no AND ar.clientidar = slsum.sl_clientid) WHEN slsum.slc_code = 12 THEN (SELECT loanxxref_no FROM Loan loan WHERE loan.loanbr_code = slsum.sl_brcode AND loan.loanslc_code = slsum.slc_code AND loan.loanslt_code = slsum.slt_code AND loan.loanref_no = slsum.ref_no AND loan.clientidloan = slsum.sl_clientid) ELSE NULL END) AS ARREFNO, slsum.tr_date, baltype.baltypeisdebit AS BaAL_TYPE (CASE WHEN coa.coaacct_type = 4 OR coa.coaacct_type = 5 OR coa.coaacct_type = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0) END) AS SHOWTHIS, (SELECT sldtl.AMT FROM Sldtl sldtl WHERE sldtl.sl_brcode = slsum.sl_brcode AND sldtl.sl_clientid = slsum.sl_clientid AND sldtl.slc_code = slsum.slc_code AND sldtl.slt_code = slsum.slt_code AND sldtl.ref_no = slsum.ref_no AND sldtl.sle_code = slsum.sle_code AND (sldtl.adj_flag = 1 OR sldtl.adj_flag = 2) LIMIT 1) AS SETUPAMOUNT FROM Slsum slsum LEFT JOIN Glcontrol glcontrol ON glcontrol.glcontrolbr_code = slsum.sl_brcode AND glcontrol.glcontrolslc_code = slsum.slc_code AND glcontrol.glcontrolslt_code = slsum.slt_code AND glcontrol.glcontrolsle_code = slsum.sle_code LEFT JOIN Baltype baltype ON baltype.baltypeid = glcontrol.bal_type LEFT JOIN Sltype sltype ON sltype.sltypebr_code = slsum.sl_brcode AND sltype.sltypeslc_code = slsum.slc_code AND sltype.sltypeslt_code = slsum.slt_code LEFT JOIN Sletype sle_type ON sle_type.sle_typecode = slsum.sle_code AND INSTR(sle_type.sle_typeactive,CONCAT(slsum.slc_code)) <> 0 LEFT JOIN Coa coa ON coa.coabr_code = glcontrol.glcontrolbr_code AND coa.coaid = glcontrol.glcontrolacct_code LEFT JOIN Loan loan ON loan.loanbr_code = slsum.sl_brcode AND loan.loanslc_code = slsum.slc_code AND loan.loanref_no = slsum.ref_no AND loan.clientidloan = 2 AND loan.loanslt_code = slsum.slt_code WHERE slsum.sl_brcode = '2' AND slsum.sl_clientid = :clientid AND (slsum.sle_code = '11' AND (slsum.slc_code = '12' OR  slsum.slc_code = '13')) GROUP BY slsum.sl_brcode, slsum.slc_code, slsum.slt_code, slsum.ref_no, slsum.sle_code
```

QUESTION: How can I make my `jpa-named-queries.properties` file work with Native SQL queries so that I don't have to format my existing long SQL queries to HQL?